# How to make Habitat Suitability Map from rasters QGIS

Tags: qgis

We're trying to make a HSI (Habitat Suitability Index) model map for a species. The thing is we have a bunch of vector layers corresponding to parts of an entire area and we have to assign a score to each one of them. So in each layer, I created a new attribute and assigned a score in each layer between 0 and 3.

Then I rasterized all those layers, but how can I join all rasters to make a map with all scores by colors?

I can only do it in vector layers with style-categorize- color by attribute

Comment: Habitat Suitability Index .. The point is to get a map by colours associated with a score.. 
With vectorial layers its no big deal, i just dont get it why I have to rasterize to be honest

Comment: I think it would be easier to merge them by keeping them as vector layers ... you have a treatment in the processing toolbox called _"merge vector layers"_ ...

Comment: If it is an index then you would just sum (or weighted sum) the rasters.